# Calculate days in controller class

Tags: date, custom-controller

i have a start date and a end date and i want to calculate number of days which should be end_date__c-start_date__c + 1.
In Apex code I am trying
Decimal number = end_date__c-start_date__c + 1;

But its throwing me a compiler error. How should i calculate this. Please Guide.

Comment: It helps to share your code and the exact error message you're receiving

Answer (score 2):

There is a Date Class method, which provides this functionality out of the box.

example copied from Date class [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_daysBetween)

> Date startDate = Date.newInstance(2008, 1, 1);
>
> Date dueDate = Date.newInstance(2008, 1, 30);
>
> Integer numberDaysDue = startDate.daysBetween(dueDate);

Comment: I don't have the values of start date and end date. They are coming from where the method is called. So I can't hardcore the values. Please suggest any other option.